# std::format pointer error C3615: consteval function 'std::_Compile_time_parse_format_specs' cannot result in a constant expression

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++20, fmt, stdformat

How to fix (stdC++20 mode VS2022)

```
#include <format>
#include <string>

auto dump(int *p)
{
    std::string resultstring = std::format(" p points to address {:p}", p);
```

resulting in:

```
error C3615: consteval function 'std::_Compile_time_parse_format_specs' cannot result in a constant expression
```

Comment: I simplified the example to use a int pointer instead of a class pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the pointer to void like this:

```
std::string resultstring = std::format("{:p}", (void *)p);
```

The problem is not with the format string itself, but rather that the templated type checking on the variable arguments FAILS for any non-void pointer types, generally with a confusing error in the header .

Comment: good answer because to tell you the truth, I had no idea what was going on other than the pointer was the problem (in my similar format code within a template)

Answer (score 1):

Formatting of non-void pointers is disallowed by default. You should wrap them in [`fmt::ptr`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#_CPPv4I0EN3fmt3ptrEPKv1T) or cast to `void*`:

```
std::string resultstring = std::format("{:p}", fmt::ptr(p));
```

Comment: fmt::ptr() looks nice - and I would prefer that over a normal cast, but it is not in the standard library - only available if [fmt library](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) is installed, so I am accepting the (void *) answser.